# How to quickly fill the miss quarterly end record for Pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have Pandas dataframe `df` like this:

```
>>> df
                  sales  net_pft
STK_ID RPT_Date                 
000876 20061231  35.737    2.195
       20070630  20.247    1.653
       20080331  16.565    0.550
600141 20071231  15.915    0.440
       20080630   7.907    0.172
       20080930  12.505    0.503
       20090331   5.360    0.342
600809 20070331  15.274    2.606
       20070630   9.489    1.947
       20070930  13.017    2.464
       20080331   3.156    0.280
```

And I want to make up the miss rows for each STK_ID against the quarterly end list RPT_DATE_LIST,

```
RPT_DATE_LIST = [
 '20060331', '20060630', '20060930', '20061231', \
 '20070331', '20070630', '20070930', '20071231', \
 '20080331', '20080630', '20080930', '20081231', \
 '20090331', '20090630', '20090930', '20091231']
```

The result should be like this:

```
>>> df
                  sales  net_pft
STK_ID RPT_Date                 
000876 20061231  35.737    2.195
       20070331  NaN       NaN
       20070630  20.247    1.653
       20070930  NaN       NaN
       20071231  NaN       NaN
       20080331  16.565    0.550
600141 20071231  15.915    0.440
       20080331  NaN       NaN
       20080630   7.907    0.172
       20080930  12.505    0.503
       20081231  NaN       NaN
       20090331   5.360    0.342
600809 20070331  15.274    2.606
       20070630   9.489    1.947
       20070930  13.017    2.464
       20071231  NaN       NaN
       20080331   3.156    0.280
```

How to do that quickly ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> def func(df, date_list):
...     lb, ub = df.RPT_Date.min(), df.RPT_Date.max()
...     pred = lambda x: lb <= x <= ub
...     df = df.set_index('RPT_Date').reindex_axis(filter(pred, date_list))
...     df.index.name = 'RPT_Date'
...     return df
... 
>>> grb = df.reset_index().groupby('STK_ID')
>>> grb.apply(func, date_list=RPT_DATE_LIST).drop('STK_ID', axis=1)
                  sales  net_pft
STK_ID RPT_Date                 
876    20061231  35.737    2.195
       20070331     NaN      NaN
       20070630  20.247    1.653
       20070930     NaN      NaN
       20071231     NaN      NaN
       20080331  16.565    0.550
600141 20071231  15.915    0.440
       20080331     NaN      NaN
       20080630   7.907    0.172
       20080930  12.505    0.503
       20081231     NaN      NaN
       20090331   5.360    0.342
600809 20070331  15.274    2.606
       20070630   9.489    1.947
       20070930  13.017    2.464
       20071231     NaN      NaN
       20080331   3.156    0.280

[17 rows x 2 columns]
```